# How to use JSON data in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a file, called `ETHBTC.json`:

```
 [{
    "open": "0.06252000",
    "high": "0.06264700",
    "low": "0.06239800",
    "close": "0.06254100",
    "volume": "681.69300000",
    "timestamp": 1521575400000
},
{
    "open": "0.06253500",
    "high": "0.06270000",
    "low": "0.06242800",
    "close": "0.06261900",
    "volume": "371.99900000",
    "timestamp": 1521575700000
},
{
    "open": "0.06261500",
    "high": "0.06280000",
    "low": "0.06257500",
    "close": "0.06266200",
    "volume": "519.11000000",
    "timestamp": 1521576000000
},
...
]
```

I am trying to save the `low` value to a variable in Node.js so I can add all the low values together, etc:

```
for(item in words) {
   var lowTotal = 0;
   lowTotal += words.low;
}
```

But I have no luck.

I'm also having trouble with the `console.log` just to log the `low` variable.

Comment: this is not valid JSON, put a `[...]` around it and first use `JSON.parse()`. Also you need to access `words[item].low` and put the `var lowTotal = 0;` in front of the for loop.

Comment: You need to give more information, do you want the value as a total? Or separately? The requirements are unclear.

Comment: @oklas not relevant to the question.

Comment: i would like one variable as a total

Comment: `lowTotal` is always reset to 0 at each iteration. Put it outside the loop

Comment: If you are able to, remove the quotes `"` surrounding the numbers otherwise you'll need to `parseFloat()`

Comment: `var lowTotal = 0;                                                                          for(item in words){
    lowTotal += parseFloat(words[item].low);
}`                                                                                                         
 try this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several issues in your code:

1. You have `var lowTotal = 0;` inside `for` which is incorrect
2. Better to use a `for` loop so that you get each item of array rather than index of array as in `for(item in words)`
3. `low` is a `string` type value so convert it to `float` type and add it to get the sum.

```js
 var words = [{
    "open": "0.06252000",
    "high": "0.06264700",
    "low": "0.06239800",
    "close": "0.06254100",
    "volume": "681.69300000",
    "timestamp": 1521575400000
},
{
    "open": "0.06253500",
    "high": "0.06270000",
    "low": "0.06242800",
    "close": "0.06261900",
    "volume": "371.99900000",
    "timestamp": 1521575700000
},
{
    "open": "0.06261500",
    "high": "0.06280000",
    "low": "0.06257500",
    "close": "0.06266200",
    "volume": "519.11000000",
    "timestamp": 1521576000000
}];
var lowTotal = 0;
words.forEach(function(word){
  lowTotal += parseFloat(word.low);
});

console.log(lowTotal)
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to parse the JSON file:

```
let fs = require('fs');
let content = fs.readFileSync('PathToFile').toString();
```

Then you need to parse it:

```
let jsonData = JSON.parse(content);
```

Then iterate over the elements. I recommend the for...of loop

```
let total = 0;
for(let element of jsonData){
    total += element.low
}
```

You can also use `Array.prototype.map` or `Array.prototype.reduce` but first stick to the basics.

Also please be sure to work on the right types:

your numbers in the JSON are saved as strings. You will have to convert them also:

```
let total = 0;
for(let element of jsonData){
    total += parseFloat(element.low);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

please use Object.values like below. Convert JSON to object though using 'JSON.Parse' method

```
let sum = 0;
Object.values(YOURJSONOBJECT).forEach(element => {

sum += parseFloat(element["low"]);

});

console.log(sum);
```

and result would be "0.18740099999999998", which is the sum of 'low' property

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over the object and sum the total

```js
var data =  [{
    "open": "0.06252000",
    "high": "0.06264700",
    "low": "0.06239800",
    "close": "0.06254100",
    "volume": "681.69300000",
    "timestamp": 1521575400000
},
{
    "open": "0.06253500",
    "high": "0.06270000",
    "low": "0.06242800",
    "close": "0.06261900",
    "volume": "371.99900000",
    "timestamp": 1521575700000
},
{
    "open": "0.06261500",
    "high": "0.06280000",
    "low": "0.06257500",
    "close": "0.06266200",
    "volume": "519.11000000",
    "timestamp": 1521576000000
}]
var lowTotal = 0;
data.map(a=>lowTotal+=+a.low)
console.log(lowTotal)
```

Comment: @James the `+` transform the string into float number

Comment: Apologies, did not see that it's very subtle. Personally I'd be more specific rather than relying on the quirks of the language but yes, this does work.

Answer (score 0):

You can [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to give an initial value & increment per item in the array

```
const json = JSON.parse('...');
const lowTotal = json.reduce((val, item) => val += parseFloat(item.low), 0);
```

**Example**

```js
const data = `[{
  "open": "0.06252000",
  "high": "0.06264700",
  "low": "0.06239800",
  "close": "0.06254100",
  "volume": "681.69300000",
  "timestamp": 1521575400000
},
{
  "open": "0.06253500",
  "high": "0.06270000",
  "low": "0.06242800",
  "close": "0.06261900",
  "volume": "371.99900000",
  "timestamp": 1521575700000
},
{
  "open": "0.06261500",
  "high": "0.06280000",
  "low": "0.06257500",
  "close": "0.06266200",
  "volume": "519.11000000",
  "timestamp": 1521576000000
}]`;

const json = JSON.parse(data);
const lowTotal = json.reduce((val, item) => val += parseFloat(item.low), 0);
console.log(`Total low=${lowTotal}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are having trouble reading json file but there are bugs in your code

`var lowTotal = 0;` should be outside for loop.

Parse String JSON object to float

Read `item` not `words`

```
 var lowTotal = 0;
for(item in words){
    lowTotal += parseFloat(item.low);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a one-liner using [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```
let sum = words.reduce((a,c)=>a+parseFloat(c.low), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should fix your code a bit:

```
let lowTotal = 0;
for(item in words){
    lowTotal += item.low;
}
```

Or you can do it in a bit different way:

```
let lowTotal = 0;
words.forEach(word => lowTotal += word.low);
```

Or the most elegant way:

```
let lowTotal = words.reduce((a, b) => {
    if(isNaN(a)) { a = a.low; }
    return a + b.low;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[For..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) is used to iterate over properties of an object. there are many ways to loop throw an array of object, the easiest is to use [for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for). one last thing the `lowTotal` variable should be declared outside the loop:

```js
var words= [{
    "open": "0.06252000",
    "high": "0.06264700",
    "low": "0.06239800",
    "close": "0.06254100",
    "volume": "681.69300000",
    "timestamp": 1521575400000
},
{
    "open": "0.06253500",
    "high": "0.06270000",
    "low": "0.06242800",
    "close": "0.06261900",
    "volume": "371.99900000",
    "timestamp": 1521575700000
},
{
    "open": "0.06261500",
    "high": "0.06280000",
    "low": "0.06257500",
    "close": "0.06266200",
    "volume": "519.11000000",
    "timestamp": 1521576000000
}];

var lowTotal = 0;
for(var i=0; i<words.length; i++){
  lowTotal += parseFloat(words[i].low);
}

console.log(lowTotal);
```

Answer (score 0):

As some other suggested. But brackets around your tickerdata to create an array.

Another suggestion.

```
var tickers = require('./JSONFILE.json')

for (const value of Object.values(tickers)) {

  console.log(value.low)

}
```

since you probably don't want to sum all low values.